# USB mouse stops working with dell D6000 dock

Tags: usb, mouse, dell, docking, usb-c

I have just got the Dell D6000 universal dock; I have connected it to my laptop via USB-C.

But after a while my USB mouse stops working; the mouse is fine never a issue when plugged into the laptop directly.

Seems to happen when watching youtube; but not always; and not exclusively. It happened when typing into a VM instance also.

All returns to normal when I unplug and plug in the mouse. The keyboard seems unaffected.

Comment: Is the dock powered by its own power adapter?

Comment: Yes; the dock has its own 130W adapter.

Comment: Sorry Adam... I don't have any more ideas for you.

Comment: It mainly happens when video is playing. I have my monitor connected via HDMI; so I will change it to display port and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Still happens when connecting via DP; however there are also graphical issues around the cursor.

Comment: What video driver do you have installed?

Comment: Nvidia 410.78; GTX1060 Mobile 6GB

Comment: The latest driver is 418.43, released 2/22/19. https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/142958/en-us

Answer (score 0):

Installing the nvidia 418.43 seems to have solved the issue.

```
apt purge nvidia*
add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
apt install nvidia-drivers-418
```

There have been no mouse dropouts for a few hours while working with youtube playing in the background.